# CSS3 Full Width Trapezoid / Polygon with text?

Tags: css, polygon, shapes

I'm trying to redo a client site that's currently not responsive and throughout the site she has long images that are trapezoids with text inside. Of course, on devices, you can barely read it.

[image]

So I'm trying to turn it into CSS using shapes. Tried a bunch of examples but nothing working at the moment. I think the difference is the examples seem to use hard width numbers instead of 100% for fluid width. I have a pen here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KmgoqE and here's the code I'm playing with as I post this (still  playing, of course):

```
h2.test-text {
  background: #000;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 1;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

h2.test-text:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border: none;
  top: -4%;
  bottom: -11%;
  left: -3%;
  right: -3%;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(50em) rotateX(-30deg);
  transform: perspective(50em) rotateX(-30deg)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already good answers

To give another try. I have opted to fix your current attempt.

Basically the problem is that the background should be on the pseudo instead of on the base

```css
h2.test-text {
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 1;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

h2.test-text:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border: none;
  top: -0px;
  bottom: -50%;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
  background: #000;
  transform: perspective(20em) rotateX(-45deg);
  transform-origin: top;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="test-text">Check out what our Clients are Saying</h2>
```

And now a *fancy* efect

```css
h2.test-text {
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 1;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 20em;
  animation: tilt 2s infinite alternate linear;
}

h2.test-text:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border: none;
  top: -0px;
  bottom: -50%;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
  background: #000;
  transform: rotateX(-45deg);
  transform-origin: top;
}

@keyframes tilt {
  from {perspective-origin: left}
    to {perspective-origin: right}
}
```

```html
<h2 class="test-text">Check out what our Clients are Saying</h2>
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. What if I just wanted to do one side instead of both left and right?

Comment: @AdamBell Use my solution and simply remove either of the pseudo, ....or do like this with _vals_ https://jsfiddle.net/psqf9m3k/1/

Comment: ..and plus 1 :)

Comment: @LGSon Thank you !  Couldn't resist to give a fancy answer ....alternating between only on right and only on left.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this effect by using the the common transparent border trick to achieve css triangles. Just instead of even borders and only one set to non-transparent you use different border sizes and two colors. I colored the right edge differently so it's easier to see what's going on.

```css
h2.test-text {
  background: #bada55;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
  line-height: 1;
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  margin:40px;
}
h2.test-text:before, h2.test-text:after {
  content:"";position:absolute;top:0;width:0;height:0;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:20px 15px;
}
h2.test-text:before{
  left: -30px;
  border-color: #bada55 #bada55 transparent transparent;
}
h2.test-text:after {
  right: -30px;
  border-color:blue transparent transparent red;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="test-text">Whatever somebody says&hellip;</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

By using pseudo elements, and skew them, you can achieve that.

This one works if the line breaks up to 3 lines, and if you need more, a media query will fix that.

```css
h2.test-text {
  background: #000;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: calc(100% - 120px);
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

h2.test-text:before,
h2.test-text:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 70px;
  background: inherit;
  z-index: -1;
}

h2.test-text:before {
  left: -35px;
  transform: skewX(30deg)
}

h2.test-text:after {
  right: -35px;
  transform: skewX(-30deg)
}

h2.test-text.nr2 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: calc(60% - 100px);
}
```

```html
<h2 class="test-text">Check out what our Clients are Saying</h2>

<h2 class="test-text nr2">Check out what our Clients are Saying</h2>
```